# T4 template changing entity to internal

Tags: c#, t4

In visual studio, I have an entity model. For some reason, one of the entities, when the DbContext is generated, is showing as internal, rather than public.

```
internal DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
```

Now in the properties window, the Access property is set to Public. I've tried switching it back and forth, running the T4 template manually after each go, and it's still coming through as internal.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried to edit the t4 template itself?

Comment: No, I didn't edit the actual template. I've edited the code generated by it, but having to change it every time I edit the edmx is frustrating.

Comment: So you have multiple entities, and only one of them is coming out `Internal`? - That wouldn't really sound like a T4 problem.

Comment: That's why I'm confused. I'm not sure if the template is wrong or if it's an error in visual studio.

Comment: No expert on the EDMX generator but looking at the T4 code you could probably just change the method: public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet). That or debug the T4 to figure out why it wants to set the set as internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying for far too long, I gave up and rebuilt the model by pulling it from the database. I couldn't figure this one out at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the `Access` property to `Public` in the Entity Designer for that specific Entity:

[image]

Comment: @DanChampagne then hit the "transform all templates" button in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: That didn't seem to have any effect that I can see.

Comment: It's going to recreate all T4-generated code. Otherwise as mentioned by others you will have to modify the template yourself, but I doubt it's a template problem if it's only happening with 1 specific entity.